# Git restart from beginning

Tags: git

Hi I am looking for a way to git reset every thing as if I have not run git init yet.

I have looked at this command

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

but I don't think this is what I want.

I am looking for a command that after running, I would have to do `git init` again.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just delete your `.git` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the repo altogether, you can just use:

```
rm -rf .git
```

That's after backing it up of course. Maybe, since you should do that anyway, it may be better to:

```
mv .git .git.bkp
```